# Rewrite rules .htaccess file of Drupal

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, drupal, drupal-7

I have installed a Drupal site in www.example.com/beta

I am trying to do the following

1. Redirecting users to /beta when they hit www.example.com which I have achieved

   RewriteBase /beta
2. Modify the URLs. For example www.example.com/beta/products should be modified to www.example.com/products. I just need to remove the /beta from the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^beta/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Regards.